# Div background opacity?

Tags: html, css

I just want add a dark overlay for my div background. I add black as a background color and set opacity to 0.5
But the problem is that child element divs also apply that opacity. See my screenshot. I just want to add that overlay for my parent div background only. Is there any specific way of doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use a semi-transparent PNG file as the background image, or just use the `RGBA` colour system:

```
background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/axn6eunx/)

`rgba()` is supported in all [modern browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-colors).

Comment: The .png solution is the one always use, it's not that flexible, but also gives you the fewest problems.

Comment: @user2521387 Actually, `rgba()` is supported in ALL modern browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-colors